# Do Karnaugh maps use a base ten numbering system?

Tags: karnaugh-map

Do Karnaugh maps use a base ten numbering system??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, binary [Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).

Comment: Thank you. I can't up vote your answer unfortunately. No rep

Answer (score 5):

The essential thing about Karnaugh maps is that when you compare the binary numbers assigned to adjacent cells, they will differ in exactly one bit. This is what enables you graphically simplify an expression by collecting adjacent cells. You could write in the decimal equivalents of the binary patterns if you like, but doing so doesn't really provide any useful advantages.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this](https://homepages.westminster.org.uk/electronics/Sixth%20Form/karnaugh_maps.htm) of interest.